# Sandbox in-app purchase, product requests work but the purchase always fails

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase

I implemented my in app-purchase and when trying to test it i.

The weird thing is that I can pick the data regarding my in-app purchase ( price, description, ect) without  a problem using SKProductsResponse, but trying to make a transaction with SKPayment always ends in failure and the app does not ask the user for input an apple id at any moment ( i never get to input one of my test users ! ).

Any hint of what could be wrong, or at least, to help me detect the problem ?

I did some sanity checking, my bundle ID, the product identifier, ect...everything is in order...

What bugs me as well is that i have done many in-app purchases in the same way in my past apps, but this never happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just terrible, the problem solved by itself, the purchases began to work.

So many hours wasted, hope that Apple improves the sandbox in the future